# How to use vectorise option in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, vector, vectorization

`Linux 3.13.0-68-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.3 gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4`

I have a simple program, I want to use vectorise actually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval stop, start;

int main() {
    int i;

    int x[8192], y[8192];
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
            y[i] = a * x[i] * x[i] + b * x[i] + c;
    }

    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);

    printf("%d us\n", stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);

      for (i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
        printf("%d\r", y[i]);
      }
    return 0;
}
```

If I use

`-O0` the time is `30 us`

`-O1` the time is `3 us`

`-O2` the time is `1 or 0 us`

but if I use

`-finline-functions -funswitch-loops -fpredictive-commoning -fgcse-after-reload -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns -ftree-slp-vectorize -fvect-cost-model -ftree-partial-pre -fipa-cp-clone -ftree-vectorize`

These are all the vectorise option I can find but the time consumption is same with `-O0`

what is the right option should I use?

Comment: `-O3` enables vectorization and a couple of other options. Your bunch of other options probably don't yield the desired effect because you didn't specify an optimization level in combination with them.

Comment: Also, your program contains undefined behaviour, it's likely that the compiler doesn't perform any optimizations at all. If I was you, I would try to design a better test case.

Comment: Note that your program doesn't use the result of your loop at all, thus it is a useless benchmark, since the compiler just eliminates the loop alltogether, and just does 2 gettimeofday calls and a printf. You can use `gcc -S` to produce the assembly code and look what's going on, for various optimization levels/flags.

Comment: Do not just post links. Site rules require to post all relevant parts **in** your question as **text** (not images).

Comment: @Olaf I modified it.

Comment: @FUZxxl  Could you give me a better case. I also tried the case here: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html

Comment: @FUZxxl Thank you very much. I find the solution, I did not use -O2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcc -O2  -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1 main.c`

Here is the output:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:19:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__suseconds_t’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%d us\n", stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
   ^

Analyzing loop at main.c:21

Analyzing loop at main.c:13


Vectorizing loop at main.c:13

main.c:13: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
main.c:5: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.
```